# how to assemble project dependencies w/o project's generated classes when using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, sbt

Since the project contains many dependencies but is still working in progress, I hope to package 2 jars: (1) the dependencies (`dep.jar`) (2) and the project classes without the dependencies (`project.jar`). So that in most of the cases I only need to update `project.jar` and execute with both jars in classpaths.

I known that in sbt I can use `sbt-assembly` to firstly `assemblyPackageDependency` and package the project classes using `package`.

How can I achieve this goal with gradle?